# Only sum up the volume of the last 5 sales per customer if the customer has more than 2 sales

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=bd86db2672fcc2d61a739206488741de)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    customerID VARCHAR(255),
    sales_volume INT,
    sales_count VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales
(customerID, sales_volume, sales_count
)
VALUES 
("Customer_01", "650", "1"),
("Customer_01", "718", "2"),
("Customer_01", "130", "3"),
("Customer_01", "455", "4"),
("Customer_01", "910", "5"),
("Customer_01", "432", "6"),
("Customer_02", "705", "1"),
("Customer_02", "718", "2"),
("Customer_03", "560", "1"),
("Customer_03", "938", "2"),
("Customer_03", "620", "3"),
("Customer_03", "182", "4"),
("Customer_03", "167", "5"),
("Customer_03", "740", "6"),
("Customer_03", "172", "7"),
("Customer_04", "260", "1"),
("Customer_05", "812", "1");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
customerID    sum(sales_volume)
Customer_01        2863    (650+718+130+455+910)
Customer_03        2467    (560+938+620+182+167)
```

---

In the above result I want to list all customers that have **more than 2 sales** but only **sum up** the `sales_volume` from **their last 5 sales**.

So far I am using this query:

```
SELECT 
customerID,
sum(sales_volume)
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1
HAVING MAX(sales_count) >= 3;
```

It works to get the **total sum** of all sales once a customer has reached **more than 2 sales** but I have no clue how I can combine this query with the **restriction** of the **last 5 sales**?

Comment: You sure get a lot of mileage from this sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to enumerate the sales *backwards* (so the most recent transaction has a value of `1`).  Then filter and aggregate:

```
SELECT customerID, sum(sales_volume)
FROM (SELECT s.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY sales_count DESC) as seqnum
      FROM sales s
     ) s
WHERE seqnum <= 5
GROUP BY customerID
HAVING MAX(sales_count) >= 3;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=39ad321320eb776c9ce7041775cff229) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: There's no way of knowing the LAST 5 sales?

Comment: @Gordon: I also liked your first version of the answer so I stored it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8b167710b8a76523b7e125ef720a733c

Comment: @Michi does `WHERE sales_count <= 5` return the last 5 or the first 5 sales?